# How to prevent mgo to unmarshal int to float64

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have unknown json structure data stored in mongodb. They have the fields to present the unix time like this:

```
"date": 1424803567,
```

I am using mgo to load them to the bson.M.

```
var result bson.M
iter := c.Find(q).Iter()
for iter.Next(&result) {
```

Those unix time fields have turned to the fload64 instead of the int.

```
 "date": 1.424728798e+09,
```

So, how to prevent that happens in the case above? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mgo does not unmarshal an integer to a float unless destination value is explicitly typed as a float by the application. Mgo is returning a float value here because the value stored in the database is a float.

You can unmarshal the float value to an integer by specifying the type using a struct:

```
var result struct {
  Date int64 `bson:"date"`
}
for iter.Next(&result) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just checked the data in the database. It is the float indeed. So, it's the issue on the data input. It is resolved by using the decode with UseNumber() instead of straight Unmarshal. Thanks!